# Validate if a resource matches a search criteria?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I am building a minimalistic subscription service. Is there any way to check if a resource matches predefined search criteria?  eg, if I have:

```
String criteria = "Observation?code=http://loinc.org|1975-2";
Observation observation = new Observation();
```

I am looking for a `checkCriteria()` operation or equivalent:

```
assert checkCriteria(observation, criteria) == true;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`SearchParamMatcher`](https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/v5.0.2/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-searchparam/src/main/java/ca/uhn/fhir/jpa/searchparam/matcher/SearchParamMatcher.java#L28) class which fits the usage scenario you're asking.

```java
import ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.searchparam.matcher.SearchParamMatcher;

//...

SearchParamMatcher searchParamMatcher = new SearchParamMatcher();

assert searchParamMatcher.match(criteria, observation, null) == true;
```